# my dashboard does not have the option to fix the header or change the theme. how can i get that to show?

Tags: headers

when I pull up my site to edit the pages there is no choice to work on the header or change a theme etc.  I can not edit my home page, make any additions to it.  I can change the rest of my pages just not the home page and think maybe the problem is with the header. and maybe the wrong link on my main page buttons

my site is:
http://www.glorydaysscrapbooking.com/

Comment: What theme are you using? What options are on the left side of your admin panel? Could you send some screenshots of the left bar in your admin panel?

Comment: Check the Themes function.php and activated plugins

Comment: What is your user level? Is your user an 'administrator'?